# Proof of convergence of an infinite sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

A question that I tried to prove is as follows.

"Consider the following sequence defined recursively by $a_1=\sqrt{a}$ and $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{a+a_n}$, where $a>2$. (The first few terms are: $\sqrt{a}, \sqrt{a+\sqrt{a}}, \sqrt{a+\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a}}}...$) Prove that this sequence converges, and find its limit.

For proving that the sequence converges, I used the following argument. Since the sequence is monotonically increasing, I can show that this sequence converges by finding an upper bound. I speculated that

$$
\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a...}}}<a
$$
However, I do not know how to prove this inequality formally. My rather informal argument for the veracity of the inequality goes like this:
$$
\sqrt{a}<a
$$
$$
\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a}}<a
$$
because $\sqrt{a}<a<a^2-a$ for $a>2$ (by the racetrack principle)
$$
\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a}}}<a
$$
because the fact that $\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a}}<a$ for $a>2$ implies that $\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a}}}<\sqrt{2a}<a$ for a>2, by the racetrack principle.

and so on. Is this kind of argument accepted? If not, how can I prove that the infinite sequence has a bound?

Please do not give the limit of the sequence, which I already found out to be $\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4a}}{2}$.

Comment: Note that if $x$ is the limit, then $x^2-a=x$.

Comment: Yes, I realize that, which is how I found out the limit using the quadratic formula. My question is whether there is a limit $x$ at all. Your equation - which I already figured out - ASSUMES that $x$ exists.

Comment: Ah well try using the fixed point theorem.

Comment: Thank you, but could you elaborate on the fixed point theorem, and how that can be used to prove the limit? I have never heard of the theorem before in my life. If needed, please explain not as comment but as answer.

Comment: Use induction. every time there is a recessive definition of something and you want to prove something about it, think about induction. You already know the base, and you practically did the step for $a_2$

Comment: "the limit of the sequence, which I already found out to be $\frac{1+\sqrt{4a}}{2}$" Not true. You do not want to be given the true limit hence I cannot correct your formula, but it is wrong.

Comment: Thank you, error was corrected (which also explains why the limit of the sequence when $a=2$ is $2$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite easy to prove your inequality by induction. $a_1=\sqrt{a}<a$ holds because $a>2>1$. Suppose $a_n<a$. Then
$$
a_{n+1}^2=a+a_n<2a<a^2.
$$
The first inequality above uses the induction hypothesis, the second the assumption that $a>2$. Now take the square root and the claim follows.